# How to set a procedure (function) to an event in delphi 7?

Tags: delphi-7

I am writing which component will run through the array like ['form1.Button1', 'form1.memo1', 'form1'] - like
And put the showms2 handler on it (form1.Button1.onclick: = showms2)

```
var
comp: array of Tcomponent;
met: Tmethod;
start off
  setlength (comp, Lines.Count);
  for i: = 0 to Lines.Count-1 do
    start off
    comp [i]: = (FindComponent (Lines.Names [i]) as TControl);
   met: = GetMethodProp (comp [i], 'OnClick');
   meth.Code: = form1.MethodAddress ('showms2');
   met.Data: = 0;
// When splitting into elements, nothing happens, is there an alternative?
```

Comment: I don't know what `: =` is meant to be, but it doesn't compile. A spot of advice for you is to be more careful and precise over what you post. Don't post fake code. Try to provide an [mcve] always. You are looking for `SetMethodProp` rather than `GetMethodProp` if you want to modify the event property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FindComponent()` does not work the way you are using it. You need to specify only the name of a component that is directly owned by the component being searched, you can't specify a chain of components, ie `Form1.FindComponent('Form1.Button1')` won't ever work, but `Form1.FindComponent('Button1')` will work, if `Form1` owns `Button1`.

Also, if you are going to set both `TMethod.Code` and `TMethod.Data` then calling `GetMethodProp()` is completely redundant and should be removed.

Also, you need to use `SetMethodProp()` to actually assign the `TMethod` to the target event.

Try this instead:

```pascal
var
  comp: TComponent;
  met: TMethod;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Lines.Count-1 do
  begin
    comp := FindComponent(Lines.Names[i]);
    if comp <> nil then
    begin
      if IsPublishedProp(comp, 'OnClick') then
      begin
        meth.Code := Form1.MethodAddress('showms2');
        meth.Data := Form1;
        SetMethodProp(comp, 'OnClick', met);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `Form1` perhaps should be `Self`.

Comment: I also wonder why use `MethodAddress` here rather than getting the address directly with `@`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan considering the OP is included `'form1.xxx'` and even `'form1'` itself in their list of names, I'm assuming `Self <> Form1` in this case. And who knows, maybe `form1` is not the actual Form class in this context, making `@` unusable. Not enough context to know one way or another.

Comment: "Not enough context to know one way or another." Exactly.